# Can I set the DPI in Spire.PDF for .Net Standard?

Tags: pdf, image-conversion, pdf-conversion

We are updating a package we have from .Net Framework to .Net Standard. We are able to use the Spire.DPF SaveAsImage() call with DPI specified.  However, when downloading the Standard package, the DPI cannot be set using this call.  Is there another way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is NOT possible.  I ended up using ABCPDF.

From Ice-Blue:

1. For .Net Standard project, you can directly install Spire.Officefor.NETStandard 7.3.2 via nuget, then the corresponding dlls will matched automatically.
2. About the DPI issue, kindly note that the .Net Standard library of our Spire.Pdf depends on the SkiaSharp, however, the SkiaSharp library itself does not support setting DPI. Thus, specifying the DPI is no longer available. What is your using scenario? Whether your project can use .Netcore to create? If so, you can install Spire.PDF via nuget to use our .Netcore dlls. It also supports setting the DPI. Look forward to your further feedback.